# Stripping out hyphens from a Date String

Tags: regex

Is it possible to strip out/substitute/replace out hyphens from a date string so that only the digits are returned in the match group?

Test Strings

```
25-11-1982

11-10-1200
```

I would like to return

```
25111982

11101200
```

What I have so far:

```
(?<date>[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{4})
```

Returns Date =

```
25-11-1982

11-10-1200
```

Link to attempt: https://regex101.com/r/3vvYHu/2/

Comment: Not just with regex; you can add captures to extract the numbers, and use those in substitution but the named group still includes the dashes: https://regex101.com/r/fErQ7a/2/

Comment: which language would you use the result in? I ask because I think you can do what you need outside of regex

Comment: For example in python you can do as follows `a = "25-11-1982" 
"".join(a.split('-'))`

Comment: Join this group? `(\d{2}(?=-)|(?<=-)\d{4})`

Comment: Do a [search for `strip out hyphen`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=strip+out+hyphens), some answers recommend simpler string-functions for that, like `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following example:
https://regex101.com/r/AcX8FL/1 
It contains regular expression as well as substitution section. 
Regex:

```
([\d]{2})-([\d]{2})-([\d]{4})
```

Substitution:

```
$1$2$3
```

Input:

```
25-11-1982
```

Output:

```
25111982
```

Comment: Simplify without character sets: `(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})`

Answer (score 0):

Use the replace-all function of your language and replace the hyphen `"-"` by empty string `""`.

#### Examples

Python:

```py
date1 = '25-11-1982'
date2 = '11-10-1200'

print(date1.replace('-', ''))  # 25111982
print(date2.replace('-', ''))  # 11101200
```

Java:

```java
String date1 = "25-11-1982";
String date2 = "11-10-1200";

System.out.println(date1.replaceAll("-", ""));  // 25111982
System.out.println(date2.replaceAll("-", ""));  // 11101200
```

JavaScript:

```js
let date1 = "25-11-1982";
let date2 = "11-10-1200";

console.log(date1.replaceAll("-", ""));  // 25111982
console.log(date2.replaceAll("-", ""));  // 11101200
```

PHP:

```php
echo str_replace('-', '', '25-11-1982');  // 25111982
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex: https://regex101.com/r/HmqLTJ/1

Which replace "-" with "".

Or, the PHP code that is generated by this:

```
$re = '/(-)/m';
$str = '25-11-1982';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```